# How can I construct UGens with more than 5 arguments in JCollider

Tags: java, arguments, supercollider

JCollider is a Java client for the SuperCollider sound synthesis server.

It has a stupid arbitrary limit of 5 arguments when constructing UGens. [(see Documentation for UGen here](http://www.sciss.de/jcollider/doc/api/index.html)) I'm referring to the ar method. They made made multiple copies of that method for variable numbers of arguments, but they stopped at 5 and I need 7. Those convenience functions look like this where they are defined.

```
public static GraphElem kr( String name, GraphElem in1, GraphElem in2, GraphElem in3, GraphElem in4, GraphElem in5 )
{
    return UGen.construct( name, kControlRate, -1, new GraphElem[] { in1, in2, in3, in4, in5 });
}
```

I tried just using the UGen.construct method myself, but it's apparently "not visible" from where I'm trying to use it (in a different package).

I then tried fixing this in the JCollider source by just extending the convenience methods to the equally stupid arbitrary limit of 7, but alas I couldn't compile it due to an ant script problem.

What is the correct way to use UGen.ar() with more than 5 arguments?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

At the time I wrote that it was Java 1.4. So I decided that 5 was a good number :) (in fact it covers some reasonable percentage like 98% or so of the ugens). You can still use the inner part of what you pasted to work around it without touching the source, e.g. call `UGen.construct( name, kControlRate, -1, new GraphElem[] { in1, in2, in3, in4, in5, in6, in7, ... });` Obviously nowadays you'd go for Java 5 style varargs.

If you are willing to use another language, give [ScalaCollider](https://github.com/Sciss/ScalaCollider)  a try, it's a much smoother experience.

Comment: Thanks, I know it's an old project, but it means a lot that you still answer questions about it. And in case you want to know what I made with JCollider, look at http://nathannifong.com/NetworkChimes/ I would be honored if you'd feature that on the list of projects using JCollider.

Comment: Hey, nice project! I will add a link once I get to doing an update!

Answer (score 0):

I managed to get around the ant build problem and recompile JCollider with the increased limit of 7.